# Delete associated link and remove associated object from array

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build out a form structure where links can be added or removed from an array and on user satisfaction with the links they have created can submit the array filled with title/link objects.

At the moment I have successfully added the jQuery functionality to add links to objects, append them to an array and then display the added links below the form, but I am not sure how I can handle the removal of the link.

I have a div wrapping the created link, which is paired to an "x" that is supposed to remove the link and object from the array on click, but at the moment all that is happening is that the "x" is disappearing. If both links are found in the same `<div>` shouldn't both be removed with the method `.parent().remove()`? My `.filter()` function is also not removing the object from the array.

**Here is my JS Bin:**

https://jsbin.com/luxavucusi/edit?html,js,console,output

**Here is the jQuery snippet that isn't working:**

```
// Remove Displayed Link
         $(this).parent().remove();

         // Grab data attribute from "x" linked to report link
         var elementLink = $(this).data("link");
         console.log(elementLink);

         // Filter the report link array for grabbed data attribute link and remove object from array
         var linksRemoval = links.filter(function(value, index, arr){
           console.log(value)
           return value.link !== elementLink
         })
```

**Here is my Full jQuery:**

```
$(function() {


   // Display Added Links Function
   function linksDisplay(title, link){
     // If "title" field is blank, use the value from the "link" field
     if (title === "" || !title){
       return "<div><a href='" + link + "'>" + link + "</a><a href='#' class='remove-link' data-link='" + link + "'>x</a></div>";
     } else {
       return "<div><a href='" + link + "'>" + title + "</a><a href='#' class='remove-link' data-link='" + link + "'>x</a></div>";
     }

   }

   // Array to store collection of link objects to be passed on form submission
   var links = [];

   // Add Link button click
    $("#linkForm").click(function() {
      console.log("Button Clicked")

      // Individual link object
      var individualLink = {};

      // Pass value from "title"
      individualLink.title = $('input#title').val();

      // Pass value from "title"
      individualLink.link = $('input#link').val();

      // Pass individual report object to links array
      links.push(individualLink);

      console.log(individualLink);
      console.log(links.length);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(links));

      // Display newly added link to div below form
      $(".report-links").append(linksDisplay(individualLink.title, individualLink.link));
    });

   // Form submission 
   $("#submit").click(function(){
      console.log("Submit Clicked")
      console.log(JSON.stringify(links));
   })

   // Remove Link Click
   $(document).on("click", ".remove-link", function(){
     console.log("Remove Link Clicked")

     // Remove Displayed Link
     $(this).parent().remove();

     // Grab data attribute from "x" linked to report link
     var elementLink = $(this).data("link");
     console.log(elementLink);

     // Filter the report link array for grabbed data attribute link and remove object from array
     var linksRemoval = links.filter(function(value, index, arr){
       console.log(value)
       return value.link !== elementLink
     })
     console.log(links);
   });

 });
```

Comment: your js bin doesnt have any remove button in it. I pasted in the code in your question that adds the remove button, and it worked as expected, it removed the whole link not just the x button.

Comment: Strange, I guess I didn't snapshot with it in there (Now it is), but when it is added, I see that the link is deleted, but the `.filter()` is not removing link object from the array. Is there a better method?

Comment: gotcha. that is a separate issue. i think you're using `filter` wrong. filter does not change the array in place, it returns a new array. so you need to reassign that to `links`, instead of setting it to `linksRemoval` which is basically a throwaway variable, ie, you want: `links = links.filter(//...`